# Partioning drive containing OS with media

Tags: partitioning, drive, storage

I currently have a drive containing a partition with windows installed. The problem is that inside this partition I have all of my media (music, books, etc).
I want to install Ubuntu on the same drive, wipe the windows partition, but moving my media to the newly created ubuntu partition.
What is the proper way to do this? 
I thought about shrinking the current partition, making a new one and copy over all of my media there, wipe the windows partition and install whatever there. Would there be a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Approach 1: a bit long

This is your approach. There's nothing wrong with it. Here's how it'll go:

Shrink Windows partition, create a new partition, copy media to new partition, install Ubuntu on Windows partition. Then, you can either copy back the data into Ubuntu and expand, or leave that "data" partition there and access it through Ubuntu.

For this approach, when you're installing Ubuntu, I would do the following steps (this is assuming your Windows partition is 100GB and you have 4GB RAM):

1. Pick "Something Else" under the "Installation Type" when installing Ubuntu. This will give you a list of the partitions you have.
2. Select the Windows partition (identify it by its size), delete it.
3. Create a partition of size 96GB, choose filesystem `ext4`, and make it use mount point `/`.
4. Create a partition from the remaining 4GB, filesystem `swap`.
5. Continue with the installation.
6. Once you're done, if you can't boot into Ubuntu, boot from your Ubuntu CD/DVD/USB, choose "Try Ubuntu", open up the program called Boot-Repair, and click "Recommended Repair". That will fix your booting problems.

#### Approach 2

Copy your media to an external hard disk, detach the external hard disk, install Ubuntu using the option "Completely wipe the disk and install Ubuntu". Once it's done, copy back your media. This approach is much easier, given that you have an external hard disk big enough.

Answer (score 0):

No at all , it is completely safe to proceed as long as you make sure all important data is passed to the newly created partition